# How to fix "TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object."

Tags: node.js, gulp, hottowel

I start getting this error for some reason and can't figure out why and how to solve it. I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

I'm using [John Papa's Hottowel Generator](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel), and when I'm trying to run `gulp build` or `gulp serve-dev`, I get this error. I already tried to update `wiredep`, `vinyl-fs` and `readable-stream` packages to latest versions, but it didn't solve the problem.

Can anyone please help me to find the source of the error and solve it?

Thanks in advance. And if you need to see some code, please, let me know what part do you need.

Comment: show us the part of the code , that causes that error, because it seems like you are passing an argument to a method or a function which is not a string or buffer or any array like object

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe, the problem is that I have no idea, what part of code is causes that error. The project worked fine before, and I didn't add any new lines of code, just started to get this error =(

Comment: Is there a way to find a source of this error?

Comment: you should consider creating an issue

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe, that may be a good idea. But I still hope to find some help here, on SO =)